# apparmor alternative for MacBook

Tags: malware, macos, sandbox

Does anyone know an alternative to apparmor for Mac? Every time I use winebottler my MacBook gets Windows viruses. Wanted to protect my Mac from it.

Comment: Unfortunately, product recommendations are off-topic here. Perhaps over at AskDifferent?

Comment: I'd recommend you using Parallels and stop using any websites that are suspicious. Or do not download any illegal/cracked software because they often have trojan/malware/adware sitting in them.

Comment: Thank you. Never downloaded an cracked software just downloaded malware bytes an the amount of Trojans that it detected. Was pretty full on. I think I have something in my router so wanted to use windows program to remove it. But don't have a windows Comp anymore. But back fired on me an it installed window viruses on my Mac detected 17 Trojans

Answer (score 1):

Very little work has been written on OS X security, especially malware issues. The book *Incident Response & Computer Forensics, Third Edition, 3rd Edition*'s Chapter 13 covers investigation of Mac OS X system integrity breaches. Of perhaps primary interest would be the section on system auditing which includes information on OpenBSM configuration and analysis.

The best recent work is from Yelp with the FOSS project -- https://github.com/Yelp/osxcollector -- based on the original -- https://github.com/jipegit/OSXAuditor

They link out to some additional resources on this page -- http://www.mac4n6.com/resources/

Another book, *The Art of Memory Forensics: Detecting Malware and Threats in Windows, Linux, and Mac Memory*, covers OS X malware from a memory capture assessment perspective. It links out to a few blogs, such as ones that cover [techniques](http://siliconblade.blogspot.com) and others that provide case studies and downloads of live [OS X malware samples](http://contagiodump.blogspot.com/search/label/OSX).

Be sure to check out the recent news from this year's BlackHat US and DEF CON. [Stefan Esser](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/08/04/apple_sudo_bypass_exploit_wild/)'s public exploit was discovered in the wild shortly thereafter and OS X malware made a lot of fanfare during that time period, including a more-recent one from [Luca Todesco](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/08/18/apple_local_root_os_x_yosemite/).